# Break down this sentence: お金がなくて最近はほとんど食べていないのです。

Tags: grammar

I don't get how お金がなくて works in this phrase, can someone help me to break it down... thank you!

Comment: Please edit your question to explain how much of the sentence you do understand and what part (e.g. what about お金がなくて) you don't understand. Once you edit your question it will be automatically considered for reopening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

なくて is the て form of ない, which is the negative of ある (to exist, to have). So:

> お金がない

Means "I don't have any money."

The て form in this case is used to link the verb to the rest of the sentence, the way we use "and" or "so" in English.

> お金がなくて

"I don't have any money, and (so)..."

The て form doesn't always imply a causal relationship with the remainder of the sentence, but in this case it does. "I don't have any money, so I've barely been eating lately."